# Command output redirect to file and terminal

Tags: linux, bash, redirect

I am trying to throw command output to file plus console also. This is because i want to keep record of output in file. I am doing following and it appending to file but not printing `ls` output on terminal.

```
$ls 2>&1 > /tmp/ls.txt
```

Answer (score 151, accepted):

Yes, if you redirect the output, it won't appear on the console. Use `tee`.

```
ls 2>&1 | tee /tmp/ls.txt
```

Comment: Does it write stderr & stdout both??

Comment: In this case error is merged into the output (`2>&1`), so the next process consuming the pipe will see both of them as regular input (in short: yes).

Comment: How do i append logs using tee?

Comment: nevermind i found it --append, -a

Comment: How to give the size of ls.txt file in above command so that it does not exceeds that given size. And once it exceeds max size, how to create a new file in that same directory (for eg: ls1.txt,ls2.txt...)

Comment: Be aware that you will loose the exit status of `ls`. If you want to retain the exit status of `ls`, or more precisely want to figure out if something in your pipe failed despite `tee` being the last (and very likely successful) command in your pipe, you need to use `set -o pipefail`.

Comment: Note: in modern versions of bash and zsh, you can use `&>` instead of `2>&1`. https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

Comment: looks like `tee` "eats" colorizing and some formatting (try with `ls`), can we avoid this drawback? May be some option for that?

Answer (score 58):

It is worth mentioning that 2>&1 means that standard error will be redirected too, together with standard output. So

```
someCommand | tee someFile
```

gives you just the standard output in the file, but not the standard error: standard error will appear in console only. To get standard error in the file too, you can use

```
someCommand 2>&1 | tee someFile
```

(source: [In the shell, what is " 2>&1 "?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-is-21) ). Finally, both the above commands will truncate the file and start clear. If you use a sequence of commands, you may want to get output&error of all of them, one after another. In this case you can use -a flag to "tee" command:

```
someCommand 2>&1 | tee -a someFile
```

Answer (score 23):

In case somebody needs to append the output and not overriding, it is possible to use "-a" or "--append" option of "tee" command :

```
ls 2>&1 | tee -a /tmp/ls.txt
ls 2>&1 | tee --append /tmp/ls.txt
```