# How to redirect ubuntu terminal output to a file?

Tags: linux, terminal, ubuntu-12.04

I have tried redirecting the terminal output to a file using `tee` and `>` as in the examples [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38126/how-to-redirect-output-to-screen-as-well-as-a-file-in-a-yet-to-be-created-direct) and the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591374/command-output-redirect-to-file-and-terminal). It worked for `echo test | tee log.txt` or `ls -l | tee log.txt`

But It does not work (does not add anything to the log.txt) when I run a command like `divine verify file.dve | tee log.txt`
where divine is an installed tool. Any ideas or alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `divine verify file.dve 2>&1 | tee log.txt`. If the program is outputting to stderr instead of stdout, this redirects stderr to stdout.

Answer (score -1):

works on ffmpeg output too

```
{ echo ffmpeg -i [rest of command]; ffmpeg -i [rest of command]; } 2>&1 | tee ffmpeg.txt
```

and tee -a   to append if file already exists

======

also   if you want to see mediainfo on all files in a folder and make sure command is also visible in mediainfo.txt

```
{ echo mediainfo *; mediainfo *; } 2>&1 | tee mediainfo.txt
```

NB:  { echo cmd; cmd; }   means the command is kept in the txt file ; without this it is not printed