# linux terminal: how to copy output to a file and print at terminal simultaneously?

Tags: linux, file, file-io, terminal, output

I would like to save output from command to a file and observe it on ubuntu terminal at once.

**Using basic:**

```
command >output.txt
```

It's not working, because the terminal shows nothing.

Is it possible to see the output in both file and in terminal window?

Comment: Terminal won't show anything as output has been printed/written to the file. Use `tee`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591374/command-output-redirect-to-file-and-terminal

Comment: Yes it is. I've tried to find the answer via google and stackoverflow before, but I've failed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [tee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) command to achieve the same.

```
command | tee output.txt
```