# Redirect output to file and terminal using ADB

Tags: android

Basically [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591374/command-output-redirect-to-file-and-terminal) only using ADB

How would I write to a txt file and the terminal at the same time.

> /system/bin/sh: tee: not found

Would I be stuck cross-compiling tee for the device?

Sidenote: I am using Cygwin and Win10 so that could be part of it.

Comment: weird, android 5.0+ seems to have it. I was able to use that command you linked in adb shell

Comment: That could be fair too I am on an old S5, which the whole problem is it won't take an upgrade.

Comment: `tee` is available on my Cygwin/Win10 install, as part of coreutils.